# Why sys time of process is showing higher when the strace command is showing significantly less time?

Tags: c, multithreading

I have written a program using C which has two threads.
Initially it was,

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    long_operation(arr[i]);
}
```

then I divided the loop into two threads, two execute concurrently.

One thread will carry out the operation for arr[0] to arr[n/2], another thread will work for arr[n/2] to arr[n-1].

long_operation function is thread safe.

Initially I was using join but it was taking higher sys time for futex system call, which I observed using strace command.

So i removed the strace command and use two volatile variable in the two threads to keep track whether thread is completed or not and a busy loop in the thread spawing function two halt the execution of later code. And I made the thread detachable and remove join.

It improved performance a little bit. but when i used time command, the sys part was taking,

```
real    0m31.368s
user    0m53.738s
sys     0m15.203s
```

but when i checked using the strace command the output was,

```
% time   seconds      usecs/call   calls  errors  syscall

55.79    0.000602           9        66           clone
44.21    0.000477           3       177           write
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ---------------
100.00    0.001079                   243           total
```

So the time command was showing that around 15 seconds CPU spend in kernel within the process. But the strace command showing almost 0 seconds was utilized for system calls.

Then why 15 seconds was wasted in kernel?
I have an dual-core hyper-threaded Intel CPU.

Comment: A system call is not the only cause for a program to spend time in the kernel. Look at interrupts for example.

Comment: @ZachP can you please tell me how can i check that?

Comment: I believe strace should work, just that your program spends a lot of its runtime in the kernel, it would be more understandable if you let us know what does your program do. Either way, it shouldn't be much to worry about

Comment: @ZachP actually when i run the loop as it is.
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    long_operation(arr[i]);
}
then the sys time is near about 0 but when i am using this method that i described earlier that's when the sys time increasing. 
Can you please ell me how to check that using stace?

Comment: Managing threads might consume time in kernel mode

Comment: @ZachP i see, thanks for your response. :)